# Rails 4 Sum by Model Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1, activerecord-relation

In my app, I have a `User` model, with a `goal_ytd` method, which performs some calculations.

In a controller, I have a variable `@users` that might be `User` or an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of `users`, and I would like to sum all of the `@users`'s `goal_ytd`s.

My first inclination was:

```
@users.sum(&:goal_ytd)
```

Which threw a deprecation warning in both cases because using `sum` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` is going away in Rails 4.1.

So, I changed the code to:

```
@users.to_a.sum(&:goal_ytd)
```

Which then threw a `NoMethodError` because, in a certain circumstance, `@users` is assigned by `@users = User` and `User` has no `to_a` method.

Assigning `@users` using `@users = User.all` throws a deprecation warning because `Relation#all` is also deprecated.

Is there a way to get all `Users` as an array? Is there a better way?

Comment: have you tried `@users.sum(:goal_ydt)`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

On Rails 4.1

If `goal_ydt` is a column in the users table:

```
@users.sum(:goal_ydt)
```

If `goal_ydt` is a method in `User` class:

```
@users.to_a.sum(&:goal_ydt)
```

Comment: How would I go about passing a parameter to the method?

Comment: `@users.to_a.sum { |u| u.goal_ytd(parameter) }`

Answer (score 5):

I like to use a combination of `map` and `sum`

```
@users.map(&:goal_ydt).sum
```

Comment: @Fran Martinez, would you kindly explain to me why `Model.map(&:goal_ydt).sum` is needed when using `group_by`. Why cannot rails do a database sum (not hash sum) when using for example `.group(:id)`? As in a standard `Model.sum(:price)`?

Answer (score 3):

You should not use enumerable methods here. Use `sum` which is defined on ActiveRecord::Relation and takes symbol as parameter. The main difference is that it will perform `SUM` query in your database, so it is much faster than pulling all the records form db.  Also if any of your record has blank value for given field, enumerable `sum` will throw an error, while ActiveRecord's one will not. In short:

```
@users.sum(:goal_ydt)
```

EDIT:

However since `goal_ydt` is not a field but a method, you have no choice but to loop over the models. The way I usually do this is by using `scoped` method:

```
@users.scoped.sum(&:goal_ydt)
```

Comment: The problem here is that `goal_ytd` is a method for users, not an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is rooted in a fundamental misunderstanding of the `Relation#all` deprecation. While `Relation#all` is deprecated, `Model#all` is not. Therefore:

```
@users = User.all
```

is still perfectly valid, while:

```
@users = User.where(first_name: "Mike").all
```

is deprecated.

So the end solution looks like:

```
@users = User.all
unless current_user.admin?
  @users = @users.where(company_id: current_user.company_id)
end
@users.to_a.sum(&:goal_ytd)
```

A new question would be: How do I sum all the users goals, preferably in one line, without loading them all into memory? I suppose that's for another day.