# ActiveRecord sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model which contains items for sale. The model is mirroring an API, so I can't change it's structure.

In this model I have the fields `price` and `sold_quantity`.

It doesn't seem right to iterate through the query with a loop.

```
current_user.items.each do |item|
  total += item.price * item.sold_quantity
end
```

Is there a way to get the same total using only ActiveRecord? Like `.sum(:price)` but multiplying by `sold_quantity`?

Comment: Just found a better way than the ugly loop, but it still iterates through results. In this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274845/rails-4-sum-by-model-method I found the way to sum by a model instance method `@items.to_a.sum(&:sold_value) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
current_user.items
  .select('items.*, items.price * items.sold AS total')
  .all
```

Or, if you want the totals and nothing else:

```
current_user.items.pluck('items.price * items.sold')
```

Comment: `pluck` is exactly what I was looking for http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Comment: That really worked, but it returns an Array containing the results of all multiplications. Just added `.inject(:+)`

Comment: current_user.items.pluck('items.price * items.sold').inject(:+)

Comment: I think `current_user.items.sum('items.price * items.sold')` will do the same thing, but in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
current_user.items.sum { |item| item.price * item.sold_quantity }
```

I hope this help you.

For more information [sum](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum) in AR

Comment: You're not using ActiveRecord here. The method you're using (and linked to) is Enumerable#sum from ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could approach this would be to move this logic into the Item class:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def total
    self.price * self.sold_quantity
  end

  def self.sold_value
    all.map{|a| a.total}.sum
  end
end
```

Here each instance of item is calculating it's own total, and a class method allows you get the sold value on any collection of items.

```
@user.items.sold_value
```