# Rails: getting an average from all the instances of a model from birthdate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, average

Im kinda new to the dev world and have the next issue:

I need to display the average age from a group of people. Since i cannot have an "age" property in the model, i defined the age method on the class as follows:

```
class Persona < ApplicationRecord


require 'date'
    def age
      now = Time.now.utc.to_date
      dob = self.fecha_de_nacimiento
      now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
    end
end
```

This is my controller :

```
 def index
@personas = Persona.order(Arel.sql("cast(strftime('%m', fecha_de_nacimiento) as integer)"))
```

This is because I need to have the table ordered by month of birth on the index view.

Now I need to show the average age of Persona, but have tried with persona.average(age), persona.average(:age) and so on and cant seem to get it to work. Is there a way to do it with average or to make the sum of all ages and then divide it by the total number of my persona instances?

Thanks in advance to anyone who might help me.

Comment: You'll need to either a) store the age in the database, b) Create an arel node or sql snippet to calculate the age from birth date in the database and avg() that or c) using sql, cast the date to integer, average it, cast it back to date and calculate age from that using ruby. a) duplicates data, can go out of sync. b) is complicated, c) is hacky and not reusable for anything else

Answer (score 0):

Just found the way to make it work. What I did was just sum all the ages and then divide it by `@personas.length` in my view with embedded Ruby like this:

```
<p>
  El promedio de edad es:
  <%= @personas.sum(&:age) / @personas.length %>
</p>
```

And it worked fine just like that!

This [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274845/rails-4-sum-by-model-method) really helped.

Comment: You might want to add `if @personas.any?` somewhere